# Schwarz Lemma Question $|f(z)| \le \left |\frac{z-1/2}{1-1/2z} \right|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be the open unit disk $D= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1\}$. Suppose $f: U \to U$ is analytic on $U$ with $f(1/2)=0$. Show that $$|f(z)| \le \left |\frac{z-1/2}{1-1/2z} \right|=\left |\frac{2z-1}{2-z} \right |$$

My approach: I want to use the Schwarz lemma but I'm confused because isn't $f(0)=0$ a condition in the Schwarz lemma? This doesn't produce it. I don't know how to go about the proof. Any help with be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use that $\frac{z−1/2}{1−1/2z}$ maps the unit disc holomorphically to itself.  You need to come up with some new function "g" to apply the lemma to that has g(0)=0.

Comment: I could just pick any g?

Comment: You need to pick one that gives you what you're trying to prove.